# Flot chart rendering unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, ruby, flot

I'm trying to display a flot chart with 3 arrays. To make things simple the arrays are all the same:

```
[[1,1],[2,3],[3,6],[4,10],[5,15],[6,21]]
```

I create the arrays with the following ruby code:

```
def flot_chart_series
  total=0
  foo=[]
  (1..6).each do |number|
    foo.push [number, total+=number]
  end
  foo
end
```

Here is my Erb processed Javascript code:

```
var fb_shares = <%= flot_chart_series %>;
var twitter_shares = <%= flot_chart_series %>;
var email_shares = <%= flot_chart_series %>;

var plot = $.plot($("#statsChart"),
  [ { data: fb_shares, label: "Facebook shares"},
  { data: twitter_shares, label: "Twitter shares" },
  { data: email_shares, label: "Email shares" }], {
    series: {
      lines: { show: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        fill: true, 
        fillColor: { colors: [ { opacity: 0.1 }, { opacity: 0.13 }, { opacity: 0.15 } ] }
      },
      points: { show: true, 
        lineWidth: 2,
        radius: 3
      },
      shadowSize: 0,
      stack: true
    },
    grid: { hoverable: true, 
      clickable: true, 
      tickColor: "#f9f9f9",
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    legend: {
// show: false
labelBoxBorderColor: "#fff"
},  
colors: ["#3071eb", "#30a0eb", "#a7b5c5"],
xaxis: {
  ticks: [[1, "JAN"], [2, "FEB"], [3, "MAR"], [4,"APR"], [5,"MAY"], [6,"JUN"], 
  [7,"JUL"], [8,"AUG"], [9,"SEP"], [10,"OCT"], [11,"NOV"], [12,"DEC"]],
  font: {
    size: 12,
    family: "Open Sans, Arial",
    variant: "small-caps",
    color: "#697695"
  }
},
yaxis: {
  ticks:3, 
  tickDecimals: 0,
  font: {size:12, color: "#9da3a9"}
}
});
```

The problem is that the chart doesnt plot 3 of the same lines, it creates lines that are increasing in value. Here is a screen shot of the graph: [flot chart screen shot](http://postimg.org/image/74rnc8t8n/)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `stack: true` is this correct? I dont find it in flot API Please check and make sure you are doing right.Please provide working fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @captain hints at in his comment this is because you are using the stacking plugin with `stack: true`.  This is going to stack the 3 identical lines on top of each other.

Compare these fiddles:  [stack true](http://jsfiddle.net/Sm3m4/2/) and [stack false](http://jsfiddle.net/Sm3m4/3/).

If you don't want to stack just get rid of the plugin (less javascript == faster loading) and the `stack: true` option.

Comment: Thank you. Sorted out the 'problem'